# Sum of digits of large numbers with a particular form

Tags: big-numbers

I used Wolfram Alpha to find the sum of digits of these large numbers but the results are " standard computation time exceeded ". Could you help me  because I want investigate these four numbers:

- $((10^{24862050}-1)/9)-2^{82589933}+24862051$
- $((10^{23249427}-1)/9)-2^{77232917}+23249428$
- $((10^{22338620}-1)/9)-2^{74207281}+22338621$
- $((10^{9383763}-1)/9)-(10223*2^{31172165})+9383762$

Comment: 111871922, 104615981, 100516425, 42227033 but I couldn't find a way to get the free WolframAlpha to do this within the limits. There are other free tools that could do this if you search for them.

Comment: I apologize for my scrape-n-paste error, the last total is 42222673. For smaller numbers WA seems to correctly understand `IntegerDigits[ ((10^9383−1)/9) − (1022*2^3117)+9383 ]` which correctly produces a list of digits, but I have not been able to find the correct wording to get WA to then sum up that list of digits. For larger numbers some buffer must overflow and it cannot understand the expression. Some may feel WA questions are inappropriate here. You might download and install and run the free Mathematica engine on your computer if possible which could easily find such totals and more.